# Passing data through <Link /> but getting undefined using React Router in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm struggling to pass some data from one component to another one using `<Link />`. I cannot pass any params to my URL so, please excuse that solution. Below are my sample files from my problem,

**App.jsx**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route exact path={'/my-dashboard/first-page'} component={FirstComponent}/>
  </Router>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**LinkingComponent.jsx**

```
const LinkingComponent = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: '/my-dashboard/first-page',
        state: { userDetails: data }
      }}
    >
      {data.firstName}
      &nbsp;
      {data.lastName}
    </Link>
  );
};
```

**FirstComponent.jsx**

```
const FirstComponent = props => {
  const {
    location: {
      state: { userDetails }
    }
  } = props;
  console.log('user-detail', userDetails);
 ....
 some data manipulations
 ....
}
```

Here, the `FirstComponent` is not directly linked or related to the `LinkingComponent`. I'm using the `LinkingComponent` in my dashboard and I am passing my 'data' there. It is receiving it properly in the `LinkingComponent`. But somehow whenever I try to access it in my `FirstComponent`, it gives me an error that it is undefined. I have already tried various solutions and read various articles, but couldn't find an appropriate solution.

Please help me with the solution here. TIA.

Comment: Everything looks correct. Do you click on link?

Comment: Yes. That page is getting routed to. Still, the value is undefined for `this.props.location.state.userDetails` as well.

Comment: Why do you use `BrowserRouter` and `Router` in one project? Remove `BrowserRouter` keep `Router` only.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem though. :(

Answer (score 1):

1. First, get rid of `Router` or `BrowserRouter`, because `Router` is usually just an alias for `BrowserRouter`. Below is the import you might see:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

And then, your **App.jsx** will be like:

```
<Router>
   <Route exact path={'/my-dashboard/first-page'} component={FirstComponent}/>
</Router>
```

2. Second, this is seriously wrong:

```
const FirstComponent = props => {
  const {
    location: {
      state: { userDetails }
    }
  } = props;
  console.log('user-detail', userDetails); // <- Seriously wrong!
  return <div>FirstComponent</div>;
}
```

Although `FirstComponent` is a function, it's not a normal javascript function but **React functional component**! You need to have a life circle method (componentDidMount) to see the `userDetails` prop.

Assuming that you know Hooks, your `FirstComponent` will be like:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"

const FirstComponent = props => {
  const {
    location: {
      state: { userDetails }
    }
  } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
     console.log({ userDetails }); // <- Better console.log with Object
  }, []) // <- empty dependency = componentDidMount

  return <div>FirstComponent</div>;
}
```

3. Also, you need to wrap your `FirstComponent` by `withRouter` HOC, which is provided by react-router, to get the `location` prop in your `FirstComponent`'s props.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-tr5iy) I've created a small example. Play with it.